# How to add OpenTelemetry StartActivity to record each method call without writing it everywhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, profiling, jaeger, open-telemetry

In a .NET 5 ASP.NET project, I have configured `ActivitySource` in the `Startup.cs` like below:

```
public static readonly ActivitySource ActivitySource =
            new ActivitySource(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name);
```

In the `Startup.ConfigureServices`, I have added the codes below:

```
services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(
                b => {
                    b.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("WebAPI"))
                     .AddSource(ActivitySource.Name)
                     .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                     .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                     .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation(o => o.SetDbStatementForText = true)
                     .AddJaegerExporter();
                });
```

Now I need to add the code below in the Controller method class, then in the business class logic & each method call to see the trace result recorded in Jaeger.

```
using var a = Startup.ActivitySource.StartActivity($"controller table data");
```

If I want to profile a WebAPI endpoint call with many method calls in between, it would be very painful to add the code above.

Is there any neat way of configuring `StartActivity` globally so each method call would be traced & recorded without having to write such code in each method call?

Comment: I am not familiar with asp.net but have fair understanding of opentelemetry, If you can share what you are trying to do in general terms I could may be help you with it.

Comment: You could [have a look official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs#optional-add-status). It might be helpful.

Comment: But I would prefer to log this kind of activity using action filter which would be more efficient and convenient

Comment: Don't forget that the AddJaegerExporter is about to be deprecated https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger/README.md